# Big query formula to write-append runs but doesn't return anything?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-bigquery, google-sheets-api

```
function appendJoin12() {
  var job = {
    configuration: {
      query: {
        query: 'SELECT * FROM [projectId:datasetId.Join2_Test],
                              [projectId:datasetId.Join1_Test] ',
        writeDisposition:'WRITE_APPEND',
        destinationTable: {
          projectId: 'projectId',
          datasetId: 'datasetId',
          tableId: 'tableId'
       }
     }
   }
 };

 var queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(job, projectId);
 Logger.log(queryResults.status);
}
```

This is the content of file Join1_Test

```
ID  Name
1   cat
2   dog
3   mouse
4   turtle
5   fish
```

This is the content of file Join2_Test

```
ID  Name
6   apple
7   orange
8   kiwi
9   banana
10  peach
```

---

This is the content of **RESULTING** file that I want Join12 (This is the tableID)

```
ID  Name
1   cat
2   dog
3   mouse
4   turtle
5   fish
6   apple
7   orange
8   kiwi
9   banana
10  peach
```

The code above runs but returns nothing, why and how do i fix that. This was used in google sheets.

There is no error message, The destination table is empty

The code works with the appends and write options in the standard big query where is says "Show Options" but the reason for this approach is to automate it.

The above select query works.

If the above is correct do i need to enable something or change some settings.

Answer (score 0):

I have to disclaim that this process works completely fine for me and I could not replicate the problem.

[insert](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/insert) is asynchronous.

> This method returns immediately. You must call jobs.get() and examine
>   the job status to learn when the job is complete. You include one and
>   only one of the following child properties in your job resource. The
>   child property that you include defines the type of job it is.

What you might run into is that because the script is asynchronous it immediately finishes and the inser job is removed but never fully executed to finish.
Before logging the results and terminating you may want to wait until the function is complete

```
var jobId = queryResults.jobReference.jobId;
while (!queryResults.jobComplete) {
  Utilities.sleep(1000);
  queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectId, jobId);
}
```